# Avro schema evolution(backward compatibility) return null with pyspark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, avro

Avro backward compatibility return null record.

I send a record endoded by schema_ver1.avsc, and a record encoded by schema_ver2.avsc to kafka,
then, I query pyspark Streaming memory sink named avro_sink3　decode by ver2 schema(avro_json_schema_ver2).

I expect records like this.

expected record

```
+-----------------------------------+
|from_avro(value)                   |
+-----------------------------------+
|{ver1_yuki_schema, login, 4, 1}   | 
|{ver2_yuki_schema, login2, 4, 1000}| 
+-----------------------------------+
```

However, I got output like below instead.

actually output1

```
+-----------------------------------+
|from_avro(value)                   |
+-----------------------------------+
|{null, null, null, null}           |   -> endoded by schema_ver1.avsc decoded by schema_ver2.avsc(record No.2)
|{ver2_yuki_schema, login2, 4, 1000}|  -> endoded by schema_ver2.avsc decoded by schema_ver2.avsc(record No.2)
+-----------------------------------+
```

How should I fixed this problem.

pyspark streming sink

```
memory_stream_check29 = df \
  .select("value").alias("value") \
  .writeStream \
  .format("memory") \
  .trigger(processingTime="5 seconds") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/kafka/avro_file11131/") \
  .queryName("avro_sink3") \
  .start()
```

query memory sink

```
spark.sql("select * from avro_sink3").select(from_avro("value",avro_json_schema_ver2, {"mode" : "PERMISSIVE"})).show(truncate=False)
```

schema_ver1.avsc

```
{
  "namespace": "root",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Device",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "id", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "type", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "sendtime", "type": "int" },
  ]
}
```

schema_ver2.avsc

```
{
  "namespace": "root",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Device",
  "fields": [
    { "name": "id", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "type", "type": "string" },
    { "name": "sendtime", "type": "int" },
    { "name": "temp", "type": "string", "default": "1" }
  ]
}
```

environment
spark3.2

Comment: I hit the same problem and it does not make any sense to me. If the schema is compatible, like in your case, it should work. At least it is what I expected :(

Answer (score 1):

from_avro expects the writer's schema to be available for deserialization. You cannot use avro_json_schema_ver2 to deserialize records written by using avro_json_schema_ver1. An alternative solution would be to deserialize using all the schemas by having schema identifiers in the record headers and then map the right schema to each record.

Answer (score 1):

The Spark open source version does not implement AVRO schema evolution as I thought it would do.

You must **always** find out the specific writer's schema version and use it in the parameter `jsonFormatSchema`. There is an [option](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#data-source-option) called `avroSchema` that you can use in order to implement a pseudo schema evolution.

I call it pseudo schema evolution because `jsonFormatSchema` must always be the specific writer's schema version, so it will not be able to work with AVRO data that was serialized with another version.

So, in your case you could do the following and it will work with data coming in version 1:

```
spark.sql("select * from avro_sink3").select(from_avro("value",avro_json_schema_ver1, {"mode": "PERMISSIVE", "avroSchema": "avro_json_schema_ver2"})).show(truncate=False)
```

**But it will NOT work for data coming in version 2 even if both of them are compatible.** So you need two different dataframes for each specific version and later you can apply `union` in both dataframes. See: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/27045 and https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26780.

In my opinion this sucks.

Databricks Runtime 12.1 and above implements its own specific version with a real schema evolution, but only works with a Schema Registry. See:
https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/avro-dataframe.html#example-with-schema-registry

Also here, someone implemented a solution to this problem (I did not test it):

- https://medium.com/@vitorf24/avro-schema-evolution-using-schema-registry-with-apache-spark-a7327c805657
- https://github.com/Orpheuz/SparkAvroSchemaEvolution